# Задача «Результаты олимпиады»

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, сортировка, список

Только начал изучать Python. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу:

**Условие:**
Во время проведения олимпиады каждый из участников получил свой идентификационный номер — натуральное число. Необходимо отсортировать список участников олимпиады по количеству набранных ими баллов от больших баллов к меньшим, а при равенстве баллов — по возрастанию идентификационных номеров. Встроенные алгоритмы сортировки не использовать.

**Входные данные:**
На первой строке дано число (1≤≤1000) — количество участников. На каждой следующей строке даны идентификационный номер и набранное число баллов соответствующего участника. Все числа во входном файле не превышают 105.

**Выходные данные:**
В выходной файл выведите исходный список в порядке убывания баллов. Если у некоторых участников одинаковые баллы, то их между собой нужно выводить в порядке возрастания идентификационных номеров.

Я пытался сам решить задачу, но в итоге ничего не получается.

Мой код:

```
n = int(input())
ipt = [[int(j) for j in input().split()] for i in range(n)]



for i in range(len(ipt)):
    imax = i
    if ipt[imax][1] < ipt[i][1]:
        ipt[imax], ipt[i] = ipt[i], ipt[imax]
    elif ipt[imax][1] == ipt[i][1]:
        if ipt[imax][0] > ipt[i][0]:
            ipt[imax], ipt[i] = ipt[i], ipt[imax]



for l in ipt:
    print(*l)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, улучшить код.

Comment: вводится только число участников, остальное из файла берётся(по условию) ... где файл с номерами и балами ?

Comment: Нет, номера и баллы участников вводятся самостоятельно (не из файла).

Comment: а как тогда расценивать ''Все числа во входном ФАЙЛЕ не превышают 105.'' ?

Comment: Эта задача с курса программирования, там не предусматривается файл, это точно. Значит это просто опечатка в условии задачи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причём тут квадраты сумм?

`a[j]>tmp` замените на функцию сравнения, учитывающую в первую очередь баллы, а при равенстве - номер.

Данные можно организовать в два списка и менять элементы одновременно, или в список туплей или списков - так проще.

```
def compare(a, b):
    if a[1] > b[1]:
        return True
    elif a[1] == b[1]:
        return a[0] < b[0]
    else:
        return False

def insertion_sort(f):
    for i in range(1, len(f)):
        tmp = f[i]
        j = i - 1
        while j >= 0 and compare(tmp, f[j]):
            f[j + 1] = f[j]
            j -= 1
        f[j + 1] = tmp

f = [[1,3], [2,8], [3,3], [4,5]]
insertion_sort(f)
print(f)

>>[[2, 8], [4, 5], [1, 3], [3, 3]]
```

Comment: Здесь невозможно читать. Отредактируйте свой вопрос, добавив актуальный код

Comment: У Вас в коде не сортировка. Я привел код, за исключением ввода.

Answer (score 1):

извините, но почему то ваш код считает не правильно
допустим на вводе

```
3 3
3 1
4 4
2 3
```

вывод получиться

```
4 4
2 3
3 3
3 1
```

Comment: это, видимо, был комментарий к предыдущему ответу?

Comment: Ага, для учёта `по возрастанию идентификационных номеров` нужно  `return a[0] < b[0]`

Comment: А можете в проге пожалуйста написать

Comment: Все, смог решить